# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkinsfile is as follow:

```
    pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Checkout Source') {
            steps {
                echo '====stage 1: SCM Poll Stage===='
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
                sh 'mvn compile -f tools/pom.xml -Dlogin.user=ABC -Dlogin.password=ENC(123+w)'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error near **ENC(123+w)**

The error in console output is

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/firstPipeline_feature_Ticket-1@tmp/durable-2b07c016/script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I'm wondering if we can't use parentheses"**()**" in **sh** command line. How should we escape this special characters?

Comment: I ran the code you put in the question through the pipeline validator and it came out clean with no syntax errors.

Comment: The question in shell. I believe you just have to quote the parameter. Use plain shell to execute your command...

Answer (score 3):

You should use `'''` for shell script calling and give the parameter as string so your should use `"`. Like this:

`sh ''' mvn compile -f tools/pom.xml -Dlogin.user=ABC "-Dlogin.password=ENC(123+w)" '''`

Comment: I think there's a difference between single and double quote and the triple one just allows multi line string.

Comment: And furthermore the triple quote can allow to give parameters of command as string. In my opinion if questioner will give the parameters as strings, it will solve the syntax error.

Comment: Say what? Parameters of command as string? I don't follow. Which level are you talking about? In context of groovy/jenkins or execution in shell? You don't need `'''`, `'` is enough.

Comment: I mean in this case: `"-Dlogin.password=ENC(123+w)"`

Comment: I got your point. But something in parentheses means run is sub-shell is shell script. But in this case the questioner don’t want to run anything. Mvn command should read the PSW parameter as string which mean quotes should be used

Comment: Thanks for your discussion. `sh 'mvn compile -f tools/pom.xml -Dlogin.user=ABC "-Dlogin.password=ENC(123+w)"'` works for me.  I didn't use `'''` to wrap this command. Only use `"` to wrap this parameter for mvn command. `ENC(123+w)` is a password string.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the reason 
If **Jenkins** **pipeline project name contains brace** in its name 
like -> **project-pipeline(develop)** 
If you have any shell commands and in the Jenkins which uses the project name then you might see this error.
sh (script: "cd ${project-pipeline(develop)}", returnStatus: true)

Comment: This completely fixed my problem. Pipeline would stop working as soon as I tried importing a global library. All because I had a "(" in my pipeline name. Sure would've been nice if Jenkins actually warned that it might be a problem. All I had was these obscure errors in the console output about some bracket and a warning to check my credentials.

Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Glad I am helpful.

Answer (score 0):

*Syntax error near unexpected token* may occur in a Jenkins job, if calling a shell script file that was stored in Jenkins credentials (secret files).

For example, if you've recently imported a credentials.xml from another Jenkins server, the secret file might have been badly decoded, so it does not contain plain text anymore.

Try to print the content of the script file before running/sourcing it, this could reveal the syntax error.